# Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_query(): Argument #1 ($conn) must be of type mysqli, PDO given

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having a problem with my PDO connection, I've been fixing it for hours but it doesn't work, I want to show the data available in the database. I have a lot of problems with Expected type 'mysqli'. Found 'PDO'.

connection.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = ""; 

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=///", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

view.php

```
<?php
            include("../config/connection.php");
            $name_surname = $_GET['name_surname'];
            if ($name_surname) {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM problems_water WHERE name_surname = $name_surname";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                while ($problems_water = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                 ?>
                 <h3>Title:</h3>
                 <p><?php echo $row["name_surname"]; ?></p>
                 <h3>Description:</h3>
                 <p><?php echo $row["phone_number"]; ?></p>
                 <h3>Author:</h3>
                 <p><?php echo $row["address"]; ?></p>
                 <h3>Type:</h3>
                 <p><?php echo $row["area"]; ?></p>
                 <h3>Type:</h3>
                 <p><?php echo $row["created_at"]; ?></p>
            
                 <?php
               }
            }
           ?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_*` and `PDO` are completely separate database interfaces, they can't be used together

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php) . It's unclear what led you to try your code this way. What made you think you can create a PDO connection and then use it with mysqli code? You will literally never find an example of that anywhere (because it makes no sense). I don't know if you just need to pay a bit more attention to tutorials, and/or not just randomly mix and match snippets of code without taking a moment to try and understand what you're doing. You can't code by guesswork/blind pasting

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=///", $username, $password);
```

so `$conn` is a PDO connection and PDO functions must be used, not `mysqli` which is an entirely different driver. You also should use prepared statements so you aren't open to SQL injections. The following changes should allow your code to function. Replace:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

with:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM problems_water WHERE name_surname = ? ');
$stmt->execute([$name_surname]);
```

and replace:

```
while ($problems_water = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

with:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

Documents:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Alternatively, you could swap the driver to be mysqli but I would not recommend that. Stick with PDO.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

(You also had an error in your outputting `$row` wasn't defined in your `while` loop so it would have thrown error notices and not given results.)